# Speed up coloring segments of a spline curve?

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, matlab-figure

I am trying to color segments of a spline curve with different RGB values. Many thanks to @Suever, I have a working version:

```
x = [0.16;0.15;0.25;0.48;0.67];
y = [0.77;0.55;0.39;0.22;0.21];
spcv = cscvn([x, y].'); % spline curve
N = size(x, 1);
figure;
hold on;
for idx = 1:N-2
    before = get(gca, 'children'); % before plotting this segment
    fnplt(spcv, spcv.breaks([idx, idx+1]), 2);
    after = get(gca, 'children'); % after plotting this segment
    new = setdiff(after, before);
    set(new, 'Color', [idx/N, 1-idx/N, 0, idx/N]); % set new segment to a specific RGBA color
end
hold off;
```

Now I am looking to speed it up. Is it possible?

Comment: The title is misleading, since the bottleneck is in the spline fitting function `fnplt()`, not in the coloring/rendering of the plot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No explicit benchmarks per se, but you can vectorise this easily by
  a. collecting the plotted points and dividing them into 'segments' (e.g. using the [`buffer`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/buffer.html) function)
  b. setting the [`'color'`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/baseline-properties.html?searchHighlight=Color%20Properties#property_Color) property of the Children **(thanks to @Suever for pointing out [this can be done on an array of object handles directly](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html#bt631jo))**

```
%% Get spline curve
x = [0.16; 0.15; 0.25; 0.48; 0.67];
y = [0.77; 0.55; 0.39; 0.22; 0.21];
spcv = cscvn ([x, y].');

%% Split into segments
pts = fnplt (spcv);   xpts = pts(1,:).';   ypts = pts(2,:).';
idx = buffer ([1 : length(xpts)]', 10, 1, 'nodelay'); % 10pt segments
lastidx=idx(:,end); lastidx(lastidx==0)=[]; idx(:,end)=[]; % correct last segment

% Plot segments
plot (xpts(idx), ypts(idx), xpts(lastidx), ypts(lastidx), 'linewidth', 10);

% Adjust colour and transparency
Children = flipud (get (gca, 'children'));
Colours  = hsv (size (Children, 1)); % generate from colourmap
Alphas   = linspace (0, 1, length (Children)).'; % for example
set (Children, {'color'}, num2cell([Colours, Alphas],2));
```

[image]

<sub>*Note*: As also pointed out in the comments section (**thanks @Dev-iL**), setting the colour to an RGBA quadruplet the way you ask (i.e. as opposed to a simple RGB triplet) is a newer (also, for now, [undocumented](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/plot-line-transparency-and-color-gradient)) Matlab feature. This code, e.g. will not work in 2013b.</sub>

Comment: +1; Thanks! Sorry, I should've mentioned in my real case, I actually need RGBA instead of RGB. I don't think `ColorOrder` is able to handle RGBA. Question updated.

Comment: hm, I'm 99% sure that in general the 'color' property cannot be set to a 4-element vector like that either.

Comment: Nope, actually it works with the `color` property, as in `set(new, 'Color', [idx/N, 1-idx/N, 0, idx/N]) `. Just tested it on R2016a.

Comment: ah, ok. sorry, I'm still on 2013b. Must be a new feature :)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou the RGBA option is undocumented.. You can usually see it when opening the `.m` files which are called when the color is set, IIRC there's a `switch` check for the format...

Comment: You could also use the `set(Children, {'Color'}, values)` way to set all colors at once

Comment: @Suever thanks, I've updated the answer to reflect this.